# Как центрировать текст, добавляемый в QPixmap?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qpainter, qpixmap

Я добавляю текст на `QPixmap` по заданным координатам вот так:

```
...
ypos, xpos = 41, 23  
pos = QPoint(xpos, ypos)
painter.drawText(pos, 'T')
```

и получаю такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это для демонстрации того, что я хочу получить на выходе, только в данном случае координаты заданные, а как можно центрировать текст в `QPixmap`, при условии, что его размер заданный, например `64x64`?

**main.py:**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QFont, QColor, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pixmap = QPixmap(64, 64)
        self.pixmap.fill(QColor('black'))
        painter = QPainter(self.pixmap)

        pen = QPen(Qt.white)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        painter.setFont(font)

        ypos, xpos = 41, 23
        pos = QPoint(xpos, ypos)
        painter.drawText(pos, 'T')
        painter.setPen(QColor('white'))
        painter.end()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В коде используется вывод в `QLabel` для демонстрации результата, но `QPixmap` будет использоваться и в других виджетах, также вместо заливки `QPixmap` может быть картинка, но я думаю это не должно повлиять на решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всегда начинаем с [чтения документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#drawText-3) и замечаем что одна из перегруженных `QPainter::drawText` может принимать на вход прямоугольник `QRect` и флаги (нам интересен `Qt::AlignCenter`)

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.pixmap = QPixmap(random.uniform(100, 200), random.uniform(100, 200))
    self.pixmap.fill(QColor('black'))
    painter = QPainter(self.pixmap)

    pen = QPen(Qt.white)
    painter.setPen(pen)
    font = QFont()
    font.setPointSize(20)
    painter.setFont(font)

    painter.drawText(self.pixmap.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, 'test')
    painter.setPen(QColor('white'))
    painter.end()

    self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.label = QLabel()
    self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.setLayout(self.layout)
    self.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.pixmap = QPixmap(random.uniform(100, 200), random.uniform(100, 200))
        self.pixmap.fill(QColor('black'))
        painter = QPainter(self.pixmap)

        pen = QPen(Qt.white)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        painter.setFont(font)

        painter.drawText(self.pixmap.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, 'test')
        painter.setPen(QColor('white'))
        painter.end()

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.label_2 = QLabel('test', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("""
            #label_2 {
                background-color: rgb(146, 43, 63); 
                color: #FBFFE2; 
                font-size: 20pt;
            }
        """)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Click me')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

    def button_clicked(self):  
        text = self.label_2.text()
        self.label_2.setText('Hello World' if text=='test' else 'test')
    
     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]